# I need help plotting this graph in R

Tags: r, graph

Here is my data:
t2=[89221345,87542657,90886527]
t1=[0.5,0.5,0.1]

I need to plot a graph so that the x axis has labels set to the values in t1 and the y axis are the corresponding t2 values. The x axis correspond to VIN numbers, so they need to be evenly spaced, and discrete points on the axis that are labaled. When i try plotting them by using plot(t2,t1), I see three big blocks on screen that don't make any sense to me.

Thanks!!

Comment: question is unclear, what do you want in plot, is t1 (x) axis numeric or categorical, and what about t2, try `t2=c(89221345,87542657,90886527)`
`t1=c(0.5,0.5,0.1)` , `plot(t1, t2)` is it close to what you want?

Comment: Can you provide the code you've already tried. Also, can you make a mockup of your desired output?

Comment: Hi! I will upload a sample soon. I'm trying to get permission from my employer to upload it to this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
require(ggplot2)
t2<-c(89221345,87542657,90886527) 
t1<-c(0.5,0.5,0.1)
qplot(factor(t2),t1)+geom_point(size=5)+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-90))
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for your help! I have found the solution to my problem; for some reason R was converting my columns to a factor datatype, that was leading to discrete plots that I had no use for. I used as.numeric(as.character( to convert my values back to int. From what I can tell, there is no appreciable loss in accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

See this [article](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html).

```
t1=c(0.5,0.5,0.1)
t2=c(89221345,87542657,90886527)
plot(1:3,t2,xaxt="n",xlab="VIN")
axis(1,at=1:3,labels=t1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that t2 are your VINs. Start of by defining the data like R would expect:

```
t2 <- c(89221345, 87542657, 90886527)
t1 <- c(0.5, 0.5, 0.1)
plot(t2,t1,xlab="VIN",ylab="???")
```

This will generate a plot with points at (89221345, 0.5), (87542657, 0.5), and (90886527, 0.1). The plot() command is looking for at minimum a vector of x values (first argument) and a vector of y values (second argument).